# How to group a column list each 2 elements

Tags: mariadb, grouping

I'm requesting a list of `DATETIME(3)` ordered by ascending order such as:

```sql
> SELECT occurred_at FROM events ORDER BY ASC;
+-------------------------+
| occurred_at             |
+-------------------------+
| 2023-11-07 10:21:34.517 |
| 2023-11-07 10:20:34.524 |
| 2023-11-07 10:19:34.514 |
| 2023-11-07 10:18:34.517 |
| 2023-11-07 10:17:34.512 |
| 2023-11-07 10:16:34.517 |
| 2023-11-07 10:15:34.518 |
| 2023-11-07 10:14:34.515 |
+-------------------------+
```

This request is pretty simple, but I would like to measure the time between each two dates (meanings compare elapsed times between the first result and the second result in a row, then the third and the fourth in another, etc... without comparing the second with the third, the fourth with the fifth, etc...).
The native `TIMEDIFF(date1, date2)` function can help me to achieve this goal, but since I My goal is to group them (maybe using `GROUP_CONCAT()` ?) by two, I would like to have a list looking like:

```sql
> THE_QUERY;
+---------------------------------------------------+
| occurred_at                                       |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| 2023-11-07 10:21:34.517, 2023-11-07 10:20:34.524 |
| 2023-11-07 10:19:34.514, 2023-11-07 10:18:34.517 |
| 2023-11-07 10:17:34.512, 2023-11-07 10:16:34.517 |
| 2023-11-07 10:15:34.518, 2023-11-07 10:14:34.515 |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

> Or even better, the `TIMEDIFF()` result of date1 and date2 in a row, date3 and date4 in the another, etc...

Since I can have many rows, I'm searched for a solution using modulo 2 and co but didn't succeed to make it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you have some information what rows belong together. But if you want to rely only on the column, you can do:

```
select min(occurred_at), max(occurred_at), timediff(max(occurred_at), min(occurred_at))
from (
  select occurred_at, cast((row_number() over (order by occurred_at))/2 as unsigned) as rn
  from events
)  as q 
group by rn desc
order by 1
```

See a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1POOUivu)
group by rn desc
order by 1

Comment: Unfortunately, this query will show me the timediff between the min date and max date, where I wanted to display the timediff between the first date and the second, the third with the fourth, the fifth and the sixth, etc... without adding the second and the third, the fourth and the fifth, etc...
So it doesn't really answer my question

Comment: @Paul-Marie. It will calculate the time difference between the pairs (first to  second, third to fourth etc.). That’s what the  `rownumber()` is there for.

Comment: yeah you'r right, after further tests it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to achieve my goal with this kind of query:

```sql
WITH data AS (
  SELECT occurred_at, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY occurred_at) AS row_num FROM `events`
)
SELECT
  CONCAT(a.occurred_at, ', ', b.occurred_at) AS occurred_at,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, a.occurred_at, COALESCE(b.occurred_at, NOW()))) AS amount
FROM data AS a LEFT JOIN data AS b
ON a.row_num = b.row_num - 1
WHERE a.row_num % 2 = 1;
```

> Note that the `LEFT JOIN` is important to handle cases where no @b is present because no closing events occurred yet

So my final query, which will sum up all times between each `events` and return it as hours look likes this:

```sql
WITH data AS (
  SELECT occurred_at, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY occurred_at) AS row_num FROM `events`
)
SELECT TRUNCATE(
  COALESCE(
    SUM(
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, a.occurred_at, COALESCE(b.occurred_at, NOW()))
    ), 0) / (60 * 60), 2
) AS amount
FROM data AS a LEFT JOIN data AS b
ON a.row_num = b.row_num - 1
WHERE a.row_num % 2 = 1;
```

I used [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/timestampdiff/) instead of [`TIMEDIFF()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/timediff/) because the former is not limited by the TIME type.
With the `TIMEDIFF()` you can't have value greater than `838:59:59.999` hours, if you do you will still get `838:59:59.999` with a warning.